# Setting a selection of rows equal to a list of strings

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe and I want to input to a slice of rows in a specific columns, where the input is a list of strings - so in each of the selected rows, I want the same list of strings.

But when I try this, I get an error:

```
df['col'].iloc[0:460] = ['x', 'y', 'z', 'q']

ValueError: cannot set using a slice indexer with a different length than the value
```

It works fine when I do the same but instead of a list of strings I just have a single string. Why won't it accept a list as input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can try `update`, chain of `iloc` with `[]` columns is not recommended

```
df.update(pd.DataFrame({'col':[['x', 'y', 'z', 'q'] for x in range(0,460)]},index=df.index[:460]))
```

Notice I create the list by for loop, due to you do not want same copy for each row, if same object then change each of the value in the list , all other row will change as well.

Use `get_indexer` and only with `iloc`

```
df.iloc[0:460, df.columns.get_indexer(['col'])[0]]=[['x', 'y', 'z', 'q'] for x in range(0,460)]
```

Answer (score 1):

It does not work because pandas interpret list type as a list of value (i.e a multiple line elements)

If you duplicate your list for the number of occurrence that you need to replace it will work:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col':['a','b','c','d','e']})

df['col'].iloc[0:5] = [['x', 'y', 'z', ]]*5
print(df)
```

that returns

```
         col
0  [x, y, z]
1  [x, y, z]
2  [x, y, z]
3  [x, y, z]
4  [x, y, z]
```

Comment: `df.col[0].append('y')` try :-), since they are the same copy ~